# Always Friday in Iceland?

Tags: discussion, meta, fun, memes

Just because I can't find where this has been asked before, could someone explain the `always-friday-in-iceland` meme?

Comment: Most of the meta memes are described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta

Comment: @Troggy: But that thread, like many others is in danger of moderator intervention. Answers have already been locked. Apparently certain moderators don't appreciate the wiki portion of this site.

Comment: @Rich B - Adding this to the memes thread won't kill anyone.

Comment: Every time a new meme is added to that thread, a pony *dies*.

Comment: @Changing: Adding to the name change meme answer won't kill anyone either, but you see how that went.

Comment: @Rich - That's because people got tired of it getting bumped. Which, while I disagree, I can understand.

Comment: @Changing: That is not an acceptable reason for a mod to lock something.

Comment: @Rich - To quote myself, "Which, _while I disagree_, I can understand." You're trying to pick a fight with someone who's on your side here.

Comment: @Rich - That's baloney. Irrational racism and murder isn't understandable, being annoyed by popular things is. Comparing the two is ridiculous. Abusing power to conduct genocide is completely unrelated to abusing power to lock a forum thread.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Haha, yes.

That [started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30134/has-tony-the-pony-been-hacked-closed) with the user [Olafur Waage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22459/olafur-waage) who used to live in Iceland.  I believe it started with someone asking a Friday type of fun question and it started as a comment, then turned into a tag.  And then people started slapping it on more fun meta questions.

Friday is kind of the official "[let a few fun questions survive on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413)" relaxed day. I believe someone asked a fun type of question and it was not Friday and someone's defense was it is always Friday in Iceland!

Comment: The "Friday answer" meme is known in Iceland from the national knowledge base "Vísindavefurinn" (https://visindavefur.hi.is/) sort of a Q&A site with answers from professors and students from local Universities and institutions. They give a silly question with a silly answer, quite fun most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

[The Friday Afternoon meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413)